# Google App Engine is not working with custom domain registered by GoDaddy

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-cloud-platform, custom-domain

I have followed the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/mapping-custom-domains) to configure my custom `.software` domain (registered previously on GoDaddy.com), but without luck.

So on GoDaddy site I have such configuration:

[image: GoDaddy Configuration]

Nameservers I got from my zone settings:

[image: NameServer Configuration]

Custom domain settings are following:

[image: Custom domain configuration]

I even disabled managed security for simplifying.
I waited 24 hours for applying dns changes but I still see:
`This site can’t be reached

server IP address could not be found

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error in browser
The same site is available via `xxx-website.appspot.com` domain.

Answer (score 1):

If GoDaddy is your registrar, it is easiest just to use their nameservers instead of Google Cloud DNS (`ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com`).

Try:

```
NS  @  ns43.domaincontrol.com
NS  @  ns44.domaincontrol.com
```

etc.

If you insist on using Google Cloud DNS, make sure you read: 
 https://cloud.google.com/dns/migrating